# Oracle query gives me error output when comparing two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

My question goes below,

```
table1
study_a   causes
12a       accident
13b       noncausal
34a       accident
45b       xxxx

table2
study_b  cases_cause
12a      accident
13b      accident
34a      noncausal
45b      xxxx
```

If the study_a and causes columns from table1 match with study_b and cases_cause columns from table2 then create a new column where we put a flag 1 for match and 0 for nonmatch. I am using Oracle 18g.

```
output

study   cause      match
12a       accident     1
13b       noncausal    0
34a       accident     0
45b       xxxx         1
```

Query tried :

```
select
    case when ((iaw.study_a is not null and os.study_b is null )) then 1 
    when ((iaw.study_a is null  and os.study_b is not null )) then 0 
    when ((iaw.study_a is not null  and os.study_b is not null )) then 1 else 0 end as match 
from table1 as os left outer join table2 as iaw on os.study_b = iaw.study_a
```

This query gives me an error saying the statement is not ended correctly, also I am not so sure if it's the right query for my expectations. Please let me know your comments.

Comment: You seem to me missing the `select` keyword...

Comment: Of course but that's not the case, I did use select. lemme update the query.

Comment: `as` is only for column aliases, not table aliases. (Also you don't need to put `((`...`))` round every condition, but it won't cause an error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *strongly* recommend using `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table2 t2
                          where t1.study_a = t2.study_b and t1.causes = t2.cases_cause
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as is_match
from table1 t1;
```

The reason why I encourage `exists` is because a `JOIN` (of any type) could find multiple matches and multiply the number of rows in the result set.  `EXISTS` guarantees that exactly all rows from `table1` are returned once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case expression as follows:

```
select a.study_a as study,
       a.causes as cause,
       case when a.causes = b.cases_cause then 1 else 0 end as match
from table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON b.study_b = a.study_a
```

Few points related to your query:

- Your query do not have `SELECT` keyword
- You have used `AS` to give alias to table. Oracle do not allow `AS` while giving alias to table
- You are complicating the `case` expression.

Comment: In your query, you are comparing only causes and cases_cause but where are you comparing study?

Comment: In the JOIN condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use decode function like below :

```sql
select t1.study_a, t1.causes, decode(t2.study_b, null, 0, 1)match
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
    on (t1.study_a = t2.study_b and t1.causes = t2.cases_cause)
order by 1
;
```